# convert two columns to new named variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a dataframe like this:

```
id  Date   value
a   2016   400
a   2017   300
a   2018   200
a   2019   100
```

and so on. I got multiple identifiers.
How can I get a dataframe like this

```
id 2016 2017 2018 2019
a  400  300  200  100
```

I have tried different solutions with merge and transposing the dataframe but it won't work. Is there a solution to this?

Thank you guys a lot in advance

Comment: I think you want to reshape your data from long to wide format, e.g. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: `t(Data[,2:3])`

Comment: using base R `reshape`: `reshape(d,  direction = "wide", idvar = "id", timevar = "Date")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `spread` from the tidyr package, if your data frame is called `d`:

```
library(tidyr)
result <- spread(d, Date, value)
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. That'll do the job!